# javafx and serializability

Tags: file-io, graphics, javafx

In the old AWT libraries, the `Point` class and the `Color` class were serializable.  Neither is in JavaFX.  I would like to save an array list of `Drawable`s to a file; here is the interface

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public interface Drawable
{
    public void draw(GraphicsContext g);
}
```

When I attempt to to this, I get bombarded by `NotSerializableExcepton`s.
What is the best alternate course of action?  All of my drawables know their color and size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom serializable form and serialize the data you need. E.g.

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext ;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color ;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.Serializable ;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream ;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream ;
import java.io.IOException ;

public class DrawableRect implements Drawable, Serializable {

    private transient Color color ;
    private transient Rectangle2D bounds ;

    public DrawableRect(Color color, Rectangle2D bounds) {
        this.color = color ;
        this.bounds = bounds ;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {
        g.setFill(color);
        g.fillRect(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        // write color:
        s.writeDouble(color.getRed());
        s.writeDouble(color.getGreen());
        s.writeDouble(color.getBlue());
        s.writeDouble(color.getOpacity());

        // write bounds:
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getMinX());
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getMinY());
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getWidth());
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getHeight());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        double r = s.readDouble();
        double g = s.readDouble();
        double b = s.readDouble();
        double opacity = s.readDouble();

        color = new Color(r,g,b,opacity);

        double x = s.readDouble();
        double y = s.readDouble();
        double w = s.readDouble();
        double h = s.readDouble();

        bounds = new Rectangle2D(x,y,w,h);
    }
}
```

If you have fields that are serializable (or primitive types), you don't mark them `transient`, and the `defaultReadObject` and `defaultWriteObject` will handle them. If you have fields that are not serializable, mark them `transient` and serialize the data in a form that can be serialized as in the example.

Obviously, since you have multiple implementations of this interface which may all need this functionality, it might benefit you to create a helper class with some static methods:

```
public class DrawableIO {

    public static void writeColor(Color color, ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.writeDouble(color.getRed());
        s.writeDouble(color.getGreen());
        s.writeDouble(color.getBlue());
        s.writeDouble(color.getOpacity());
    }

    public static Color readColor(ObectInputStream s) throws IOException {
        double r = s.readDouble();
        double g = s.readDouble();
        double b = s.readDouble();
        double opacity = s.readDouble();

        return new Color(r,g,b,opacity);
    }

    public static void writeBounds(Rectangle2D bounds, ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getMinX());
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getMinY());
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getWidth());
        s.writeDouble(bounds.getHeight());
    }

    public static Rectangle2D readBounds(ObjectInputStream s)  throws IOException {
        double x = s.readDouble();
        double y = s.readDouble();
        double w = s.readDouble();
        double h = s.readDouble();

        return new Rectangle2D(x,y,w,h);
    }
}
```

and then of course the methods in your `Drawable` implementations reduce to something like

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
    s.defaultWriteObject();
    DrawableIO.writeColor(color, s);
    DrawableIO.writeBounds(bounds, s);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    s.defaultReadObject();

    color = DrawableIO.readColor(s);
    bounds = DrawableIO.readBounds(s);
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of this.  I don't understand why simple stuff like points and colors are not serializable and why you have to serialize their state.

Comment: Serialization is rarely used any more; most modern applications use marshaling of some kind (XML or JSON for example) to transmit and/or persist state. Those solutions are far more flexible as the same representation can be used with different implementation classes (e.g. domain classes with Java Beans or with JavaFX properties).  I can see deciding that it just wasn't worth supporting.

Comment: However in some cases, James, and I'm not talking about marshalling objects over a network, it's easier to flatten complex object graphs for saves, like in games: for instance, where there might be dozens of complex collections that would otherwise need flattening to a file manually.