# JavaFX old cells in table are shown with new one

Tags: java, javafx

I have made simple table where user can search  books, and buy it. In one scene there is search label, and than, when search button is clicked, new scene is opened with search results in table. Problem is, when I enter for example, book name to search, it shows in table, but when I go back, and enter new book name to search, there are cells in table with previous search alongside new one. And I want old search records not to show when I enter new search parameter. I do not use JavaFX properties becouse I get books from server, and JavaFX properties are not serializable. It is like table is not refreshing. I've tried to implement code from similar questions from this site, but no results.
Code for my table (last column is check box).

```
            TableView<Knjiga> table = new TableView<Knjiga>();
            ObservableList<Knjiga> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

            table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY); 
            TableColumn<Knjiga, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<Knjiga, String>("Naziv");
            TableColumn<Knjiga, String> authorCol = new TableColumn<Knjiga, String>("Autor");
            TableColumn<Knjiga, String> costCol = new TableColumn<Knjiga, String>("Cijena");
            Callback<TableColumn<Knjiga, Boolean>, TableCell<Knjiga, Boolean>> cellFactory;
            TableColumn checkCol= new TableColumn<Knjiga, Boolean>();
            table.setItems(data);
            nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Knjiga, String>("bookName"));
            authorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Knjiga, String>("authorName"));
            costCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Knjiga, String>("cost"));
            checkCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Knjiga, Boolean>("checked"));                 
            cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<Knjiga, Boolean>, TableCell<Knjiga, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {
                 final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                 final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null) {
                        checkBox.setDisable(true);
                        checkBox.setSelected(false);
                    } else {
                        checkBox.setDisable(false);
                        checkBox.setSelected(item.equals(true) ? true : false);
                        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                                for(int i = 0; i < fromServer.size(); i++)
                                    fromServer.get(i).setQuantity(fromServer.get(i).getQuantity() - 1);
                            }
                       });
                    commitEdit(checkBox.isSelected() ? true : false);
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.setGraphic(checkBox);
            refresh(table, data);
            return cell;
        }
    };      
            checkCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("checked")); 
            checkCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

Comment: Aside: Just because the JavaFX properties are not `Serializable`, it doesn't mean your model class that uses them can't be. Just use custom serialization by implementing the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods. See, e.g. [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039557/javafx-and-serializability). (Also... doesn't everyone just communicate with a server using JSON these days anyway?)

Comment: Yes, they do. Problem is that I can not use JSON becouse it is not allowed for my app. (College project).

Comment: Fair enough. Consider using JavaFX properties anyway though, it makes thing play much better with the controls.

Answer (score 1):

You should null out the text & graphic when the cell is empty, it will clear the previously populated cells. In your case, the graphic is enough.

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: @MGogic If that doesn't work, you probably need to create a [MCVE] and edit your question to include it.

Comment: @ MGogic - You clearly don't set the graphic to `null` when the cell is empty (`item == null`) You may just include `cell.setGraphic(null);` where `item == null`.

Comment: In that case, compiler says that variable cell might not have been initialized.I think that this is not a problem with only checkbox column, problem is with the other columns also
@James_D
I will do that today.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thing was, that when I send ArrayList of Books from server to client, I didn't clean list, so server sends old and new objects.