# Serialization of a list, objects don't hold values

Tags: java, serialization, javafx

I'm serializing and sending a Map Class object :

```
public class Map implements Serializable {
    private List<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    public int WIDTH = 22;
    public int HEIGHT = 18;
    private Tile[][] board = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    boolean rotated;

    public Map(){
         for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
                    Tile tile = new Tile(x, y);
                    board[x][y] = tile;
                    tileList.add(tile);
                }
         }          
    }
```

As you can see Map is serializabe, same goes to Tile that extends from Rectangle. But when I try to retrieve that list from Map after sending it to client every Tile in list is empty like :

```
Rectangle[x=0.0, y=0.0, width=0.0, height=0.0, fill=0x000000ff]
```

How do I make it keep its values? I really need to do that because if all Tiles are like this then my map is just empty. Yes, when I read Object in client I cast it to Map.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`, that class is not serializable, and neither are the classes representing the properties it holds. So either you are using a custom serialization (post the code) or you are getting runtime exceptions...

Comment: ok I didn't know that Rectangle isn't serializable. Any ideas how to make it work then? I never made custom serialization.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039557/javafx-and-serializability

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thanks to that thread I made custom serialization :) Hope you will have a great day :) And I would be glad if you could answer my another questions if I get any.